# How to connect to a remote database with JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, playframework

I'm trying to connect to a remote database via JDBC. Here's my connection string:

```
db=mysql://user:password@blablabla.rds.amazonaws.com/dbname
```

At a first glance it seems like it should work, but on trying it, I get the error:

```
Cannot connected to the database, An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.
```

I'm trying to use Play framework (1.2.x) and have described this db connection in the conf file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following on from duffymo, the string you want to use is `jdbc:mysql://blablabla.rds.amazonaws.com/dbname?user=user&password=password` as documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is the wrong URL.

You need the MySQL [Connector-J](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) JDBC driver JAR in your CLASSPATH.

The URL should look like this:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

I would recommend not putting the credentials in the URL.  Add them in Java.

If you're getting an error, please post the stack trace.  That will help to diagnose what you did wrong.

Can you connect to that database using the MySQL admin tool?  Can you ping that server?  Can you telnet to that port?  If not, Java won't connect, either.  Is there a firewall between your client machine and the database server?  If yes, then the MySQL port has to be open for you.